# Django model form saves m2m after instance

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.4

I am having an issue with the way Django class-based forms save a form. I am using a `form.ModelForm` for one of my models which has some many-to-many relationships.

In the model's save method I check the value of some of these relationships to modify other attributes:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.m2m_relationship.exists():
      self.some_attribute = False
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Even if I populated some data in the m2m relationship in my form, I `self.m2m_relationship` when saving the model and surprisingly it was an empty `QuerySet`. I eventually found out the following:

The `form.save()` method is called to save the form, it belongs to the `BaseModelForm` class. Then this method returns `save_instance`, a function in `forms\models.py`. This function defines a local function `save_m2m()` which saves many-to-many relationships in a form.

Here's the thing, check out the order `save_instance` chooses when saving and instance and m2m:

```
instance.save()
save_m2m()
```

Obviously the issue is here. The instance's `save` method is called first, that's why `self.m2m_relationship` was an empty `QuerySet`. It just doesn't exist yet.

What can I do about it? I can't just change the order in the `save_instance` function because it is part of Django and I might break something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel's answer gives the reason for this behaviour, you won't be able to fix it.

But there is the `m2m_changed` signal that is sent whenever something changes about the m2m relationship, and maybe you can use that:

```
from django.db.models import signals

@signals.receiver(signals.m2m_changed, sender=MyModel.m2m_relationship.through)
def handle_m2m_changed(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        # Do your check here
```

But note the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) say that instance "can be an instance of the sender, or of the class the ManyToManyField is related to".

I don't know how that works exactly, but you can try out which you get and then adapt the code.

Comment: So what the doc says is basically that the signal will be triggered if both by `MyModel` and an instance of the model it is related when either makes a change in the existing association?

Comment: Yes, there is an invisible table in between that is MyModel.m2m_relationship.through, if that changes then the signal is sent, regardless of how that happened. I don't know which instance is sent though, you'd need to try that out.

Comment: Well yeah it really doesn't matter because it's only going to be `MyModel` being the one who changes it. And if it was the other one I guess I'd still one the m2m changed action to be applied anyway.

Comment: Should have been receiver, but .through should work.

Comment: ok it's an absurd bug my IDE is having. It insists it should be `though` instead of `through`...

Comment: by the way, you included `self` as an argument, that is wrong, is it not? the function must be defined out of `MyModel`'s scope.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I am answering questions in between waiting for my code to run to its next error, not very concentrated :-)

Answer (score 2):

But it would be impossible to do it any other way.

A many-to-many relationship is not a field on the instance, it is an entry in a linking table. There is no possible way to save that relationship before the instance itself exists, as it won't have an ID to enter into that linking table.

Comment: so what can I do? Some post-save action to modify what I want based on the m2m?